# How do I get Unicode 9 on my phone?

Tags: keyboard, emoticons

I have a 3rd Gen Moto G running Android 6.0 and I have seen no sign of the [dumpling](https://emojipedia.org/dumpling/) emoji. Or the [chopsticks](https://emojipedia.org/chopsticks/) or [flat shoe](https://emojipedia.org/flat-shoe/), which prompted me to look into the [clown face](https://emojipedia.org/clown-face/).

The clown face is part of the [emoji 3 spec](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-3.0/) that was released in 2016. The others are from the 2017 character set.

My phone is stock Android, not rooted.

Is there a right way (or a wonky way -- I'm flexible) to get the current Unicode emoji set on my keyboard? I'm just using the built in keyboard. ⌨️

Comment: There's a wonky way, but it requires root. Is your Moto rooted?

Comment: What's your Android version? Since emojis are linked to that

Comment: It's not rooted. Android version is 6.0